# "How about going to Germany tomorrow" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do you say "How about going to Germany tomorrow" in German?

> 1. Wie wär's damit, morgen nach Deutschland zu fliegen?
> 2. Wie sieht es, morgen nach Deutschland zu fliegen?

Are there other alternatives for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Wie wär's damit, morgen nach Deutschland zu fliegen?

Not wrong, but not perfectly idiomatic.

> 1. Wie sieht es **aus**, morgen nach Deutschland zu fliegen?

Was halten Sie davon, morgen nach Deutschland zu fliegen? Könnten Sie morgen nach Deutschland fliegen?

Who is asking whom, in what context? Is that a "suggestion" by your boss, a wife asking her husband, or what exactly?

Comment: How do you it if you're a boss telling your employer and if you're telling your friends to go to Germany and about a husband telling his wife? thanks

Comment: It will depend. A boss politely telling an employee would perhaps say something like: "Könnten Sie morgen nach Deutschland fliegen?". A suggestion to a group of friends could, perhaps be worded as "Was haltet ihr davon, morgen nach Deutschland zu fliegen?", while the husband asking his wife could use something like "Wollen wir morgen nach Deutschland fliegen, was hälst Du davon?" or "Wie wäre es, wenn wir morgen nach Deutschland flögen?".

Comment: As a boss, you say: "Ach übrigens, Sie fliegen morgen nach Deutschland. Holen Sie sich das Ticket im Sekretariat ab."

Comment: I'd actually use "Wie sieht es damit aus, morgen nach Deutschland zu fliegen?" in the second example because otherwise nothing in the first part of the question refers to the second part.